# about Multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I don't quite understand Multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance. plz help me. Here is my little test:

```
class Test1
{};

class Test21 : public Test1
{};

class Test22 : public Test1
{};

class Test3 : public Test21, public Test22
{};

int main()
{
    Test1  * t1 = new Test3();
    delete t1;

    system("pause>NUL");
    return 0;
}
```

I got an error: `Error  1   error C2594: 'initializing' : ambiguous conversions from 'Test3 *' to 'Test1 *'`.
WHY?

Then I tried like this:

```
class Test1
    {};

    class Test21 : virtual public Test1
    {};

    class Test22 : virtual public Test1
    {};

    class Test3 : public Test21, public Test22
    {};

    int main()
    {
        Test1  * t1 = new Test3();
        delete t1;

        system("pause>NUL");
        return 0;
    }
```

Now I got another error: `Debug Assertion Failed!`

Can someone explain me about Multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first piece of code has the exact problem that virtual inheritance solves: you have a diamond in your inheritance hierarchy. `Test21` and `Test22` both inherit from `Test1`, so when you inherit from both of them, you actually get *two* versions of `Test1` in your hierarchy, so it is ambiguous as to which one you wish to use.

The solution, is in your second sample: virtually inherit from `Test1` so that you just get a single version.

However, your code has undefined behaviour.

```
Test1  * t1 = new Test3();
delete t1;
```

You delete a derived instance through a pointer to a base class without a virtual destructor. This means that the `Test3` object is not correctly destroyed.

You should add virtual destructors to your classes:

```
virtual ~Test1() = default; //c++11
virtual ~Test1() {}; //prior version
```